# Get current time in milliseconds using cython

Tags: python, time, cython, milliseconds

I would like to convert a function written in Python to Cython. At some point, I would need to get a random value from a list. To ensure that I will get a different value each time; I wrote the following code:

```
t = time()
random.seed(int(1000*t) % 2**50) 
random_replicate = random.sample([5,8,4,6,4,65,5,6,2,1,3,8,7,9,31,4], 1) 
random_replicate
```

I tried converting it to Cython like:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

```
%%cython 
import numpy as np
import random 
cimport numpy as np
from libc.time cimport time,time_t

cdef time_t t

t = time(NULL) 
random.seed(int(1000*t) % 2**32) 
random_replicate = random.sample([5,8,4,6,4,65,5,6,2,1,3,8,7,9,31,4], 1) 
random_replicate
```

But for some reason, when I try to re-run the code within seconds, the sampled value does not change.
I would need to wait for more than a minute to get a different value.

Comment: [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) already uses the system time by default.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue. My problem was that I had to fix a random value x1 while not fixing a random value x2 (which is why I thought of using the current time to select a seed)

Comment: Given that you should only be setting the seed once, why bother translating that part to typed Cython? Your existing code should be fine

Comment: @DavidW In the same cell of my full code, I needed to enable randomness for some lines, and disable it for others.